# Access List from ParseQueryAdapter

Tags: android, arraylist, android-listview, parse-platform, baseadapter

So, I am running up against a limitation of the Parse SDK here, and I don't know how to proceed.

I have a ListView that I am setting the adapter to from a subclass of the ParseQueryAdapter, which itself extends the BaseAdapter class.

Normally with an adapter, I pass the list along to the Adapter constructor in order to get access to the list I am dealing with, so that I can call getCount, getItem, etc. by accessing the size/index of that ArrayList.

I can't do that with the ParseQueryAdapter because it takes a ParseQueryFactory as part of the constructor, and it doesn't resolve it's items until they are fetched from the Parse app online...

Now the ParseQueryAdapter *does* have a List of Objects, which is exactly what I need, expect that it is Private... so even though the getItem() and getCount() methods exist, there is no way - AFAIK - to use them, as I have no access to the dataset that is fuelling my adapter...

Further to this, I would normally use getView(), which returns a position alongside my View, and everything would be snappy. Except Parse overrides that and provides a getItemView() method which resolves the Parse Object that is fetched from the cloud and passes it *instead* of the integer for position...

So, two questions here:

1) Is there another way in which I can access the list that is feeding an adapter ? I can hack a way to pass the resolved query into a list and pass that into the adapter later, by listening to addOnQueryLoadListener(), but that seems bad design and might take a while, handcuffing my UI.

2) Am I being naive in my understanding of how to use get getItem() and getCount() methods ?

Comment: You said "I can't do that with the ParseQueryAdapter because it takes a ParseQueryFactory as part of the constructor, and it doesn't resolve it's items until they are fetched from the Parse app online... "  are you saying you want to get a count of the items before they've been fetched?  I don't see how you could do that other than by running a separate count query.  The adapter doesn't have that information available before fetching items from the database.  I'm not totally clear on what problem(s) you need to solve.

Comment: I dont need to get it before they are fetched... i just need to get it after. But when it is fetched, it stores it in a private list.

Comment: Do you need the list or the count?

Comment: Well, I need the count and the item at an index... so I assume I need the list, no ?